# facebook api graph post on group wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

can one help me?
I try on my account in my group (i´m admin of the group) to post.
(as graph)

I have two functions. a posting on my own wall, which works without errors.

Now I woltle with the second function in the group post ..
Unfortunately, so far without success.

Function 2 give me false back as response.

My scopes
user_groups,publish_actions,email,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos,manage_pages

```
    function PostMessage(){

    $postString = 'message='.rawurlencode($this->getMessage()).'&uid='.$this->getUId().'&attachment='.urlencode($this->getAttachment()).'&'.$this->getAccessToken();

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    //print_r($response);
    curl_close($curl);

}




function PostGroupMessage(){

    $postString = 'message='.rawurlencode($this->getMessage()).'&uid='.$this->getUId().'&attachment='.urlencode($this->getAttachment()).'&'.$this->getAccessToken();


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$this->getGroupId()."/feed");  // Neither group name nor the groups function id 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

}
```

EDIT:

This is a dump from the object before I post the run:

```
object(fb_send)#1 (6) {
  ["m_AppId":"fb_send":private]=>
  string(15) "xxxx"
  ["m_SecretId":"fb_send":private]=>
  string(32) "xxxx"
  ["m_UId":"fb_send":private]=>
  int(xxxx)
  ["m_AccessToken":"fb_send":private]=>
  string(56) "access_token=xxxx"
  ["m_Message":"fb_send":private]=>
  string(101) "Besuchen Sie www.modelweb24.de - Die neue kostenlose social community für Fotografen und Fotomodelle!"
  ["m_Attachment":"fb_send":private]=>
  string(258) "{"href":"http://www.modelweb24.de","name":"Wir begrüßen ","caption":"","description":"auf www.modelweb24.de","media":[{"type":"image","src":"http://www.modelweb24.de/ow_static/themes/OWD-Nyx/images/logofb.png","href":"http://www.modelweb24.de/"}]}"
}
```

Then i do PostGroupMessage() and $response is bool(false).
No more Errors

EDIT 2:

https://graph.facebook.com/180243765369952/feed/?access_token=xxxxx give me all news on group wall

Edit 3:

i have send the parameter ?method=POST and now i became a error.
what permission am I missing?

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error from the API?

Comment: i have send the parameter ?method=POST and now i became a error. what permission am I missing?                                       {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Comment: You haven't been granted user_groups and publish_actions (or publish_stream) permissions by the user - you're also calling deprecated APIs in `PostMessage()`- i suggest checking the current documentation instead of whichever example or sample code you're using

Answer (score 0):

While creating the application you all need to have the group access permission for your friends that is "friends_groups" and "offline_access".

You can check it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer